# DLL or web service for common functions?

Tags: c#, design, web-services, wcf, vb.net

We have a variety of basic functions (date utilities, email sending, internal math calculations, etc) that are currently in an old VB.NET project.

We're going to move towards C# and I'm wondering if we should write a new library that our applications can reference as a DLL or should we create a web service that our applications can call to do these things?

My current thought is for basic functions that return simple objects we can create a web service.

Edit: the main debate for us is that if we use a DLL that we deploy with various apps we have to then redeploy the DLL to all of them if we update it in the future. With a web service since the apps would all hit an endpoint we just update that.

Comment: I lack the C# expertise to give a proper answer, but my instinct would be service if it's in charge of managing some form of persistent information (e.g. your user database) or doing something computationally expensive (e.g. continuous integration?) and DLL if it's "just" utility functions that can be used pretty much anywhere (e.g. most of your examples).

Comment: A web service could be many thousands of times slower for just 'internal math calculations' than a local DLL.  I think you need to look at the specific bits of functionality in question rather than a one-size-fits-all approach.

Comment: Requiring potential customers to hit a web service for basic date/maths operations has the strong potential to become irritating. If they can't reach a good internet connection this could really hit the performance of your app, something the customer may not understand and so they may simply become frustrated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your entire stack is .net there is not much value to creating web services.  Just reference the DLLs in the .net components that need them, it will be faster as there is no serialization or extra network hop involved.

However, for cross platform purposes, web services are the way to go.  Then you can have a .net client (ASP MVC app), java client, native mobile client, etc. that all consume the functionality provided by your .net service.

This adds tremendous value when you don't know what clients will be using your functionality or if your organization has several technology stacks.  However, the addition of web services does add some overhead to your architecture in regards to network and serialization of messages.  Web services are more flexible/future/forward thinking so you can swap out or use multiple front ends for the same service.

Comment: I like the speed and ease of not having the web service. How do you handle an upgrade of the functions in the DLL? Don't you have to re-deploy all the apps with the new version?

Comment: Yes, one would have to do that.   Alternatives could be loosely coupling with MEF or Unity.   In those scenarios, the only references would be contract DLLs which contain the interface(s).  Then you can swap out implementations pretty easily.  Most of the time this isn't a big deal because everywhere I have worked the build and deploy process is rigid and regimental so changes get deployed in a consistent fashion.

Answer (score 6):

Having a separate business tier needs justification as it involves lots more work and costs more in performance (see: [MS-Business Layer](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/NOTE-ws-gloss-20040211/#webservice)). According to one definition of [Web Services](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/NOTE-ws-gloss-20040211/#webservice), a Web Service is not generally required unless you are communicating between different physical tiers. Accordingly, a DLL may fit best for what you describe. It is common to use Web Services to communicate across systems for database/file access. The difference between a tier and a layer is important (see [Tiers vs. Layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120438/whats-the-difference-between-layers-and-tiers)).